# How can I distinguish between new deployments and not - Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, webhooks

I'm new at K8S, so perhaps there is a simple solution to my problem.
Using this [tutorial](https://medium.com/ibm-cloud/diving-into-kubernetes-mutatingadmissionwebhook-6ef3c5695f74), **I'm creating a mutation webhook** whose goal is to add information to pod specifications (using mutation webhooks).
The webhook should patch only new pod deployments and not replica sets, scale-ups, or scale-outs.

**How can I distinguish between those cases (new deployments and not)** with [corev1 pkg](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/core/v1) or any other way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the content of [the `request.kind`, `request.subresource` and `request.operatrion` field of the `AdmissionReview` object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#request) sent to the admission control webhook to distinguish a CREATE/UPDATE Deployment request from a scale request or a CREATE/UPDATE ReplicaSet request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
How does the object will look in green-field (new deployment) and how does it look in brown-field (scale-up/scale-out, replica set)?
How can I deploy pods in order to check this behavior (green-field vs. brown-field)?

Comment: A new Deployment object would have `request.operation` = "CREATE". An update to an existing Deployment object would have `request.operation` = "UPDATE".